# Por que o PHP aceita instanciar uma classe através de um valor de uma variável, mas não de um vetor?

Tags: php

Por que o PHP aceita que eu crie uma classe através de uma variável dessa forma:

```
$MeuController = 'posts';
$controller = new \app\controllers\admin\$MeuController();
```

Mas dessa forma não:

```
$MeuController[0] = 'posts';
$controller = new \app\controllers\admin\$MeuController[0]();
```

O caso real é que pego as rotas através de um array em um projeto MVC, e ao tentar criar dessa forma eu não consigo, tenho que fazer assim:

```
$MeuController = $ArrayController[0];
```

Estou fazendo algo de errado ou é uma limitação?

Comment: O problema parece ser o namespace, fiz um teste sem ele e criou o objeto.

Comment: Tenta o `dfinal` de vez `meucontroler()`. Assim `$this->meucontroller`

Comment: @VictorMorais, estou tentando criar uma nova classe, não utilizar um objeto dentro de uma instância, portanto o $this-> não seria válido nesse contexto.

Comment: @rray realmente, consegui criar sem o namespace. Pra criar com o namespace parece que e só na gambiarra, pegando a linha **app\controllers\admin\$MeuController()** e transformando em uma string já com o valor de $MeuController concatenado e criar a classe a partir do nome dessa string. Será que estou fazendo errado ou tem outra forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tenho certeza, mas se isto não funciona é provavelmente para evitar variáveis complexas, isto pode dificultar o interpretador php, tanto que no php7 algumas coisas ficaram mais limitadas, conforme a [referencia do php7](https://github.com/tpunt/PHP7-Reference#uniform-variable-syntax)

### Sintaxe de variavel uniforme

Esta mudança traz "ortogonalidade" muito maior aos operadores de variáveis em PHP. Ele permite que para um número de novas combinações de operadores que foram anteriormente não permitidos e assim introduz novas maneiras de alcançar certas operações.

```
// nesting ::
$foo::$bar::$baz // Acessa a propriedade $baz de $foo::$bar

// nesting ()
foo()() // Executa o retorno de foo()

// Operadores em expressões incluidas semelhantes ao javascript
(function () {})() // Sintaxe IIFE do JS
```

A capacidade de combinar arbitrariamente operadores variável veio de reverter a semântica de avaliação da variável indireta, propriedade e referências de método. O novo comportamento é mais intuitivo e sempre segue uma ordem de avaliação da esquerda para a direita:

```
                        // maneira antiga         // nova maneira
$$foo['bar']['baz']     ${$foo['bar']['baz']}     ($$foo)['bar']['baz']
$foo->$bar['baz']       $foo->{$bar['baz']}       ($foo->$bar)['baz']
$foo->$bar['baz']()     $foo->{$bar['baz']}()     ($foo->$bar)['baz']()
Foo::$bar['baz']()      Foo::{$bar['baz']}()      (Foo::$bar)['baz']()
```

Note que a "nova maneira" funciona nas versões mais antigas.